# Surface dilatation/erosion on a mesh

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, mesh

I am performing plane detection on a 3D mesh. To fill small holes, I want to perform a dilatation/erosion step. For each planes I know the equation and the corresponding facets (represented by a set corresponding to the ids of the facets).

Currently, I have the following algorithm :

```
set<int> sFacetsDil;
for(set<int>::iterator it = Planes.sFacets.begin(); it != Plane.sFacets.end(); it++)
{
    Facet f = facetMap.at(*it);
    vector<Facet> vFacets = facetAround(f);
    for(int i = 0; i < vFacets.size(); i++) {
        if(isNotInPlane(vFacets[i]))
            sFacetsDil.insert(vFacets[i].id);
    }
}
Plane.sFacets.insert(sFacetsDil.begin(), sFacetsDil.end());
```

I do roughly the same thing for the erosion step. However this is quite ineffective: some facets are inside the plane and don't have to be visited for the dilatation steps. I understand I could compute the border of the plane, but I think in the end it would end at iterating over all the facets to find it... Moreover, there are some cases where I'd like to do multiple dilatation steps. So every time the border would have to be computed.

I have the standard halfedge structure for the mesh.

Does anyone know if there is a standard algorithm for this problem?